# Adding withCount in mongodb request I got Illegal offset type error

Tags: laravel, laravel-mongodb

In laravel 9 with MongoDB(jenssegers/mongodb 3.9) I added withCount in request :

```
$subscription = Subscription
    ::getById($subscriptionId)
    ->withCount('userSubscriptions')
    ->firstOrFail();
```

and got error :

```
[2022-08-16 14:02:18] local.ERROR: Illegal offset type {"userId":"62fb9ff9f74eb576f803a7b2","exception":"[object] (TypeError(code: 0): Illegal offset type at Project/vendor/jenssegers/mongodb/src/Query/Builder.php:373)
[stacktrace]
#0 Project/vendor/jenssegers/mongodb/src/Query/Builder.php(201): Jenssegers\\Mongodb\\Query\\Builder->getFresh()
#1 Project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(698): Jenssegers\\Mongodb\\Query\\Builder->get()
#2 Project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(682): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder->getModels()
#3 Project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/BuildsQueries.php(296): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder->get()
#4 Project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(582): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder->first()
#5 Project/app/Http/Controllers/Admin/SubscriptionController.php(162): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder->firstOrFail()
#6 Project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(54): App\\Http\\Controllers\\Admin\\SubscriptionController->edit()
#7 Project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(45): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction()
#8 Project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(261): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch()
#9 Project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(204): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()
#10 Project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(725): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()
```

I tried to debug this error in src/Query/Builder.php file:

```
$columns = [];

// Convert select columns to simple projections.
\Log::info(varDump($this->columns, ' -1 $this->columns::'));
foreach ($this->columns as $column) {
    $columns[$column] = true; // THIS LINE RAISED ERROR 
}
```

I see in log file:

```
[2022-08-16 14:02:18] local.INFO: Array(2) : -1 $this->columns:: : Array
(
    [0] => subscriptions.*
    [1] => Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression Object
        (
            [value:protected] => (select "subscription_id" from "user_subscriptions" where "subscription_id" exists ?) as "user_subscriptions_count"
        )

)
```

Relation is set in app/Models/Subscription.php :

```
public function userSubscriptions()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\UserSubscription', 'subscription_id', '_id');
}
```

This relation is used in boot method :

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    static::deleting(function ($subscription) {
        $subscription->userSubscriptions()->delete();
    });

}
```

and all related userSubscriptions are deleted ok. Error only on withCount.

How that can be fixed ?

**MODIFIED BLOCK # 1:**

After some attempts I managed to run the reqiest with adding “->select” into the request

```
$subscription = Subscription
    ::getById($subscriptionId)
    ->withCount('userSubscriptions')
    ->select('*','user_subscriptions_count')
    ->firstOrFail();
```

I do not have any runtime error, but in resulting data there no “user_subscriptions_count” or any “count” fields.

I tried to debug source code by error trace and see that, say in
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php line 698 var $columns has values::

```
 Array
(
    [0] => *
)
```

Have anybody used withCount with jenssegers/mongodb  ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a limitation/bug in the package as seen here https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/issues/1339

The exact error means that it tries to assign an object (the `Query\Expression` object) as an array key which is obviously invalid (you can only use scalar values e.g. ints/strings). So it seems it simply isn't supported.

There appears to be somewhat of a workaround by using Laravel's `$appends` property e.g. `$appends = ['userSubscriptions'];`, however this does not eager load that data so it is inefficient to use this for large datasets.

If you have an idea for a solution you can create a PR for the package (but you need some in-depth knowledge about Laravel's query classes)